# Two Apache secure websites on the same server

Tags: apache, https, virtual, hosts

On my webserver i already have an instance of GitLab that works under HTTPS. But every website i access under HTTPS goes to the same GitLab instance, no mather what I put under the virtual hosts in secure.conf. How can i have 2 websites under HTTPS with the same Apache installation?

Comment: Did you try to provide two https server entry port with different port . e.g one on port 443 and the other on 8443 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very recent for me, but i think you could use 2 different virtual host in your conf file. Each of them can be use for each of your website.

Enjoy !

Comment: i made that, but it always goes to the first one only.. the gitlab

Comment: have you restarted the apache service since then you have change the config ?

Comment: ^^ I think this link should help you, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost , maybe have you forget the NameVirtualHost ?